# Solving Redirect Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I know what is causing the Redirect loop in my code, I am just not sure how to fix it.  First, my code.

```
switch (Request.QueryString["Error_ID"])
{
    case "1":
        // Error Code 1 is when a user attempts to access the Admin section and does not have rights to.
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        break;
    case "2":
        // Error Code 2 is when a user is not currently Active.
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
        break;
    default:
        // Default is View Index 0 for default access.
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        break;
}

// Get current username.
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

// Test to see if user is Active.
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HSEProjRegConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [active] FROM [tbl_Person] WHERE username LIKE @username", conn))
    {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "%" + userName + "%");

    var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    bool registeredAndActive = (bool)res;

    if (registeredAndActive)
    {
        // Active Condition. The DEFAULT in SWITCH() will take care of displaying content.
    }
    else
    {
        // !Active Condition.  Shows an alternative version of the default page where the user is told they do not have access.
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx?Error_ID=2");
    }
}
```

The point of the code is to first check for a Query String in the SWITCH() method in case one is provided on a later page.  Then it grabs current AD username logged in with, and then checks a user database to see if the user is marked Active.  If so, it does nothing as it will allow the page to load as normal.  If not, then it redirects to the same page but appends an Error_ID so that I can display a different View saying that the user does not have access.  I am pretty sure this is where the redirect loop is coming from.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can eliminate Redirect Loop?  I tried doing a `Request.Url.ToString()` and then a `!var.Contains` to do the Redirect, but I couldn't make that work either.

EDIT: I should note that I am interested to hear if anyone has any alternatives to `Response.Redirect()`.  It works, but originally, I was using `Response.End()` and that didn't allow any code to run so came up with using `Response.Redirect()` and a `QueryString` to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if your user is active **twice**. Also, in the second check, you keep redirecting the page to itself, which keeps doing the checks.

Your first check is here:

```
switch (Request.QueryString["Error_ID"])
{
(...)
case "2":
    // Error Code 2 is when a user is not currently Active.
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
    break;
(...)
```

and your second check is here:

```
    if (registeredAndActive)
    {
        // Active Condition. The DEFAULT in SWITCH() will take care of displaying content.
    }
    else
    {
        // !Active Condition.  Shows an alternative version of the default page where the user is told they do not have acces.
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx?Error_ID=2");
    }
```

So the second check redirects the page to itself, and it keeps looping forever.

The easiest way to fix this, IMHO, is to not check if your current user is active if your error code is "2", i.e. you could either:

1) Stop the page execution if Error_ID is 2, i.e. change the first check to:

```
case "2":
  // Error Code 2 is when a user is not currently Active.
  MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
  Response.End(); // <--- this will stop the execution before reaching the first block
  break;
```

2) Don't redirect the page again, if Error_ID is 2, i.e. change your second check to:

```
if (registeredAndActive)
{
    // Active Condition. The DEFAULT in SWITCH() will take care of displaying content.
}
else
{
    // !Active Condition.  Shows an alternative version of the default page where the user is told they do not have acces.

    if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex != 2) { // check if the page has already been redirected
      Response.Redirect("default.aspx?Error_ID=2");
    }
}
```

IMHO, solution 2 seems to be the cleanest and most elegant of the two

Comment: Perfect and so simple.  Thank you.  I went with solution 2 as well.  And thanks for the explanation.  I knew that was where the issue was coming from, but hadn't properly grasped how and why.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this:

```
if(MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex != 2)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HSEProjRegConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [active] FROM [tbl_Person] WHERE username LIKE @username", conn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "%" + userName + "%");

      var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
      bool registeredAndActive = (bool)res;

      if (registeredAndActive)
      {
        // Active Condition. The DEFAULT in SWITCH() will take care of displaying content.
      }
      else
      {
        // !Active Condition.  Shows an alternative version of the default page where the user is told they do not have acces.
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx?Error_ID=2");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to perform the database check if the query string value (Error_ID) is not 1 or 2.  The way the logic is written, you will always check for whether or not the user is active and if they are not, then it will keep sending the Error_ID=2 query string value to the page and you will be stuck in a loop.  I would recommend separating out the logic to test for the query string into a separate method and have it return a Boolean of whether or not to attempt to query the database for the Active value.

Comment: I would recommend that your current method be split into three separate methods; HandleQueryString, GetCurrentUserName and IsUserActive.  You are doing too much in your single method here and that is probably where part of the confusion of how to fix this is coming from.  By separating your logic out, it allows you to break down the functionality into pieces and potentially reuse the logic elsewhere.  For instance, you could have the database logic in a Data-Access Layer (DAL) and then other .aspx pages could utilize this IsUserActive method if need be.